# mailto link not working after wheel event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have build an html page to demonstrate the problem.
Please load this document in Google Chrome:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var allow = true;
window.addEventListener("keydown", EvKeydown);
window.addEventListener("wheel", EvWheel);

function EvKeydown(ev) {
   window.document.body.innerHTML += "key ";
   window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";
}
function EvWheel(ev) {
   if (allow) {
      allow = false;
      window.document.body.innerHTML += "wheel ";
      window.setTimeout(function() {allow = true}, 500);
      window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My mail program (MS Outlook) runs every time I press a key.
Turning the wheel runs it only at the first time after the document is loaded, and if no key was pressed before.
Clicking any mouse button "resets" that and the wheel runs it again, but only one time.
I have tested this also in MS IE and Edge. It works perfectly.
Can anyone throw some light over that?

Comment: why are you creating an allow variable?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the allow variable and if statement and it will run everytime

```
<script language="javascript">

window.addEventListener("keydown", EvKeydown);
window.addEventListener("wheel", EvWheel);

function EvKeydown(ev) {
   window.document.body.innerHTML += "key ";
   window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";
}

function EvWheel(ev) {
  window.document.body.innerHTML += "wheel ";
  window.setTimeout(function() {allow = true}, 500);
  window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";

}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the allow test is just to prevent successive mailto runnings when the wheel is turned more than one step. Removing it doesn't change anything, please test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite some time on this, and so far, this is the only option I could come up with.

Depending on the purpose of your code, adding the following line will do what you are trying to accomplish.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = window.location.href },500);
```

Full HTML:

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <script type = "text/javascript">
             window.addEventListener("keydown", EvKeydown);
             window.addEventListener("wheel", EvWheel);

             function EvWheel(ev) {
                window.document.body.innerHTML += "wheel ";
                setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = window.location.href },500);
                window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";
             }

             function EvKeydown(ev) {
                window.document.body.innerHTML += "key ";
                window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com";
             }
         </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Thank you Moses, but in my tests it seems that `window.location.href = "mailto:user@domain.com` doesn't really changes `window.location.href`, so `document.location.href = window.location.href` doesn't runs the mailto protocol, but simply reloads the page.

Comment: Maybe this is a hidden setting of Chrome, one of these stupid ideas Google and MS love so much.  It's like saying "Running is very dangerous, you can fall, hit your head and die. So we will break your leg to prevent you from running."